# Pandas Openpyxl error "<class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm getting this error while loading a downloaded .xlsx file from a website

```
TypeError: expected "<class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

I saw some solutions here, but they are telling me to resave the file manually, which is not an option for more than 10.000 files.

It is a normal .xlsx file without any formulas or vba, only data.

Is there a solution for this without me having to change the versions of my libraries, I had to downgrade Pandas and XLRD to the version 1.2.0 for a solution to work. Since I'm deploying to a server, changing the versions may create a conflict with other projects that I'm running.

```
try:
     pd.read_excel("Espelho.xlsx",  engine='openpyxl')
except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

This is the file:
[Espelho.xlsx](https://easyupload.io/stnmfd)

**Edit**

This is known issue as described in github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40499.
 
The question is about how to workaround the problem and does not need additional debugging details.

Comment: Can you provide the xlsx file you are are having issues with or the web site you downloaded it from ? And the lib versions you need to use?

Comment: That is **not an error message**. Error messages, in Python, are several lines long, and start with `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and end with a line that names some kind of error (like `TypeError` or `ValueError` etc. etc.). We cannot help you unless we actually see what you are doing. Please read [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146.

Comment: @moken I've just uploaded it

Comment: It seems you have seen the github issue with pandas, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40499. Your excel file exhibits the same characteristics but can be opened if first resaved with xlwings though there may be a loss of some styling, obviously I don't know what the original file looks like. I have updated the code in the answer to reflect your use with pandas and tested with your file. While you don't want to change pandas libs are you able to use xlwings to 'fix' the files before opening with pandas?

Comment: @moken Oh yes, I should be able to do that. It is not a library that is running in this server. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw another similar query on github and their only solution was to open with win32.com resave or roll back pandas. Therefore something like this may do the trick without having to change versions or separately modify the files.
The example file provided was tested with this code.
If the xlsx file has an **expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>** exception when opening then use xlwings to open and save with new name and try opening the file again which should work second time and allow you to read the data.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd


path = 'Espelho.xlsx'
path2 = "renamed_" + path

while True:
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to open workbook; error: ")
        print(e)
        wingsbook = xw.Book(path)
        wingsapp = xw.apps.active
        wingsbook.save(path2)
        wingsapp.quit()

        path = path2
    else:
        break

for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```