# Pandas can't open an XLSX file

Tags: python, xlsx

I'm trying to open a XLSX file and and I encounter unforeseen difficulties.

Here is my code:

```
df=pd.read_excel('data - 2017.xlsx')
print(df.head())
```

Here is the first error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/X/PycharmProjects/compta/extraction.py", line 7, in <module>
    df=pd.read_excel('data -2017.xlsx')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1233, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 522, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 533, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.fills = fills
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py", line 26, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I read other posts on Stack Overflow. Among other adivce, I tried to add

```
engine="openpyxl"
```

Still the same issue. I also tried `pd.ExcelFile`, the result is below.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.ExcelFile('data - 2017.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(df)
```

After running that, it gives me the the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/X/PycharmProjects/compta/extraction.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.ExcelFile('data - 2017.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1233, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 522, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 533, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.fills = fills
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py", line 26, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/sequence.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I, of course, updatd Python and Openpyxl.

Comment: That code looks standard enough, and I dare say it has opened other .xlsx files on other people's computers. So it seems there's something peculiar to your .xlsx file. The error seems to mention styles: could you try creating a copy of your .xlsx file without any fancy styles or formatting, just the data, and see if your code will read that?

Comment: Perhaps some fill property in the excel file itself? Also maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72282629/13317272